# How to invite users to a Stack Overflow chat group?

Tags: support, chat

I have created a new chat group. Is it possible to invite related developers to my chat group? Is there any option to invite developers into a chat group?

I have recently created the chat group.

Comment: That can't be done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The formal way to invite someone to a user-specific chat room is done in the following way:

1. Find the user in [list of Stack Overflow chat-users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=all&sort=name) or [list of Stack Exchange chat-users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=name), based on which chat network you want to invite that particular user:

[image]

Note that while you may have a (parent) user account on some SE site, a chat account is a subsidiary account, since [only certain people are allowed to participate (minimum **20** reputation)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

2. Expand the chat user profile by clicking on the appropriate user:

[image]

3. Enter the name of the chat room and click on "start a new room with this user":

[image]

or choose from an existing room, by using the "invite" option.

---

Alternatively, if the both users are already in the same chat room, just ask/invite directly. Perhaps, invite them to a new room by clicking on their gravatar and select "start a new room with this user":

[image]

Formerly it was possible to invite a user to a specific chat room this way as well, but that functionality has been removed/changed:

[image]

Note that [all the conversations are free, open, and public to read by anyone](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#what).

Comment: I find this way too difficult. It can definitely be improved. :) I would suggest a "chat with user" button on the profile page; this is what I would expect. A 'chat with OP' would also make sense (eg. the person who asks the question).

Comment: @PacMan-- is correct this is a quite difficult way a button for chat should be there in userprofile based on their reputation