# Should we merge/synonym-ise [mirth] and [mirth-connect] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [mirth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth) and [mirth-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth-connect) mean one and the same thing. Actually Mirth is (was?) the company that own the Mirth Connect product. We do not create tags for company.

**Tag info for [Mirth](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mirth/info):** (363 questions)

> Mirth is an open source cross-platform interface engine with a focus on medical message formats (HL7, CCD, CCDA, DICOM, and more) that enables bi-directional sending and transformation of messages between systems and applications over multiple transports available.
>
> Mirth is based on the open source Mule ESB engine to provide speed, stability and security in a flexible environment.
>
> More information on Mirth Project web page.

**Tag info for [Mirth Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mirth-connect/info):** (84 questions)

> Use this tag to ask about usage of Mirth Connect, the open source interface engine.
>
> Mirth Connect is an open source interface engine. Mirth Connect is focused on the healthcare community and many of it's use cases are centered around healthcare based messaging like HL7, CDA, CCD, CCDA, DICOM, and other clinical messaging formats. It is also well suited to more general formats like CSV, XML, and generic database calls.
>
> More information on Mirth Connect is available from: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/dashboard.action - Wiki http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/dashboard.action - Forums
>
> Mirth Connect is often known as just "Mirth" but Mirth is the company that sponsored the Mirth Connect project. They made several other major products including Mirth Match (an EMPI), Mirth Results (a CDR), Mirth Mail (a DIRECT email server), and Mirth SignOn (a SAML compliant IdP). Mirth is now a part of NextGen.

Many questions use both the tags.

There are no specific tags for any other product from *Mirth the company* mentioned in above quote. So, on Stack Overflow, Mirth always mean Mirth Connect at least till now. If needed in future, a specific tag for product can be created like [mirth-match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth-match).

Should we merge/synonym-ise [mirth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth) and [mirth-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth-connect) tags in following direction?

[mirth-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth-connect) ← [mirth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth)

Comment: @Bhargav: I cannot vote on that synonym proposal; no enough score on tag. Not sure how to attract tag experts to that proposal or this question.

Comment: See [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312430/how-to-gather-support-for-tag-synonyms)

Comment: @BhargavRao: As you instructed, I created chat room (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191237/synonym-ise-mirth-and-mirth-connect-tags) to discuss this topic. But, I am not able to figure out how I can invite those users to existing room. The way mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253410/5779732) allows to invite to **new** room. There is no way to invite for existing room. Can you help please?